# Rotation around 2 axes include unwanted Rotations

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions

I want to spin an object around x and rotate y axis to a direction.

```
    Quaternion qr = Quaternion.Euler(transform.eulerAngles.x, 0,0);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation,qr,Time.deltaTime*5);

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation(xRotationSpeed), 
                         transform.eulerAngles.y, 0);
```

x and y Rotations combined make weird rotations and sometimes even rotate z even though I have it set to 0.

Comment: What do you mean align y to a direction?

Comment: align y rotation to a direction.

Comment: That sounds impossible, if y axis is fixed in a direction, you can but rotate the object around y axis.

Comment: I want to rotate around x with xRotationSpeed permanently and rotate towards players input and return facing towards world position when theres no input. Code Line 1 and 2 gets called. I even tried just setting eulerAngles.y to 0 in transform.rotation when theres no Input but that makes the xRotation rotate backwards and sometimes with more speed somehow. Is it because I call transform.rotation twice? Do I need to get the x, and y value in one call?

Comment: You could describe it as a ball that is rolling and changes direction. Thats what I want to achieve with the rotation.

Comment: If you just want to achieve this, you can put the ball under another gameobject. You roll the ball around x axis and turn the direction of the parent one. Do you have any reason to use just 1 gameobject?

Comment: In general you would probably rather use the `localRotation` not the global one!

Comment: I managed it with 2 gameobjects. But I was really looking for another answer to fix it. Isnt it possible to make it with one gameobject?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that yawing an object while rolling.

Notice that the rotation is applied from right to left.

```
const float ROLL_SPEED = 120f;
const float YAW_SCALE = 60;

float _lastYawBase;

void Update()
{
    var yawBase = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    var tsf = transform;

    tsf.localRotation =
        // 4. apply new yaw
        Quaternion.Euler(0, yawBase * YAW_SCALE, 0) *
        // 3. roll
        Quaternion.Euler(ROLL_SPEED * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f) *
        // 2. revert last yaw
        Quaternion.Euler(0, -_lastYawBase * YAW_SCALE, 0) *
        // 1. current rotation
        tsf.localRotation;

    _lastYawBase = yawBase;
}
```